# Json Schema file not loading using json.loads()

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

I have a valid json schema, which works fine if I make a variable like

```
schema = {

....

}
```

and use `validate('some json object' , schema)`.

However, if I save the same schema in a text file and read the text file, upon using `json.loads('schema text read from file')` it gives the error:

```
No Json objects could be loaded.
```

My question is, Is Json Schema a valid json object which can be loaded from a file using `json.loads()`. If there is any other method please help me with that.

Comment: A JSON schema should be valid JSON. I would guess yours is not.

Comment: A JSON schema is a string and your first example creates a dictionary.

Comment: Thank Fabian, In case of Dictionary the validate function works. But in case of string it does not. Can you tell me how to convert a string to dictionary in python?

Comment: @user1743297 string = '{"a": 42}'; json.loads(string)

Comment: Thanks Fabian, What you wrote generally works, but there is something wrong with my schema file, either its too big or may be something wrong with json.loads library. Or may be I have some error in it.

Comment: I have now tried loading that schema file using eval() and it worked. But json.loads doesn't work. Thanks for your help man.

Comment: @user1743297 `eval()` is a bad idea. Please post your JSON file somewhere so we can have a look (if it's big consider using http://pastebin.com/ ). Also update your post with the code that reads from file and tries to convert to Python objects.

Comment: sounds like you put `schema = {}` in your file, remove the `schema = ` , even better dump the schema with simplejson.dump

Comment: Thanks alot guys, I am quite sure eval is the worst possible way to do that. And I can't share the json or the schema file, its from work. 

And in the text file its not schema = {}, its just like this {...} and using eval i am writing it like variable = eval(text from text file). I will try the json.dumps thing. That might fix any incompatibilities.

Comment: @user1743297 Make sure that your JSON uses double-quotes.

Comment: It would help if you told what JSON Schema implementation you used